# If statement within a JSON selection?

Tags: javascript, json, n8n

In the JSON below, I am attempting to select the raw price value when the price is_rpp = True. This can sometimes be the first price or it can be any of N number of prices listed but most of the time there is none or ONE is_rpp = True price.

Is this possible?

As an example, using {{ $json["price"]["value"] }} does select the price for me but I want the is_rpp = True price.

Thank you

```
{
    "position": 1,
    "title": "Apple USB-C to Lightning Cable (2 m)",
    "asin": "asintest",
    "link": "https://www.amazon.com/",
    "categories": [{
        "name": "Electronics",
        "id": "electronics"
    }],
    "image": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/",
    "is_prime": true,
    "rating": 4.8,
    "ratings_total": 15213956,
    "prices": [{
            "symbol": "$",
            "value": 29,
            "currency": "USD",
            "raw": "$29.00",
            "name": "$29.00",
            "is_primary": true
        },
        {
            "symbol": "$",
            "value": 35,
            "currency": "USD",
            "raw": "$35.00",
            "name": "$29.00",
            "is_rrp": true
        }
    ],
    "price": {
        "symbol": "$",
        "value": 29,
        "currency": "USD",
        "raw": "$29.00",
        "name": "$29.00",
        "is_primary": true
    },
    "page": "1",
    "position_overall": 1
}
```

This will be used within N8N: https://docs.n8n.io/code-examples/expressions/jmespath/#an-alternative-to-arrow-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
{{ $jmespath($json.prices, "[?is_rrp == `true`] | [0].value") }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you can do using [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function:

If it returns `undefined`, meaning there's no items with `is_rpp = true` condition met inside of `prices` array.

```js
$json.prices?.find(p => p.is_rrp)?.value
```

```js
const $json = {
    "position": 1,
    "title": "Apple USB-C to Lightning Cable (2 m)",
    "asin": "asintest",
    "link": "https://www.amazon.com/",
    "categories": [{
        "name": "Electronics",
        "id": "electronics"
    }],
    "image": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/",
    "is_prime": true,
    "rating": 4.8,
    "ratings_total": 15213956,
    "prices": [{
            "symbol": "$",
            "value": 29,
            "currency": "USD",
            "raw": "$29.00",
            "name": "$29.00",
            "is_primary": true
        },
        {
            "symbol": "$",
            "value": 35,
            "currency": "USD",
            "raw": "$35.00",
            "name": "$29.00",
            "is_rrp": true
        }
    ],
    "price": {
        "symbol": "$",
        "value": 29,
        "currency": "USD",
        "raw": "$29.00",
        "name": "$29.00",
        "is_primary": true
    },
    "page": "1",
    "position_overall": 1
};

const rrpPrice = $json.prices?.find(p => p.is_rrp)?.value;

console.log(rrpPrice);  // 35
```

Comment: hmm for some reason that doesn't work but it might be a limitation of N8N: https://docs.n8n.io/code-examples/expressions/jmespath/#an-alternative-to-arrow-functions

Comment: Judging by the document, the syntax should be `{{ $jmespath($json.prices, "[?is_rrp==true].value") }}`

Comment: this is so close, no syntax error but it is only returning the previous value... ie: in this case it returns 29 instead of 35...

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ $json.prices[?(@.is_rrp == true)].raw }}
```

This will give you the raw price value when **is_rrp** is **true** in the **prices** array.

Note that JSONPath expressions may vary depending on the specific implementation

Comment: I think you are onto something with the limitation on the specific implementation... the code about isn't working (it is saying invalid syntax). here is more info on the limitations: hmm for some reason that doesn't work but it might be a limitation of N8N: https://docs.n8n.io/code-examples/expressions/jmespath/#an-alternative-to-arrow-functions